# A wise way to select only those optional named parameters that have a value

Tags: ruby

I'm building a client for some third-party app A. I have many methods that accept a bunch of parameters, some of which are optional. I'm using named parameters:

```
def func1(a: nil, b:, c:, d:, e: nil)
    # ...............

    call_to_client_internal(a: a, b: b, c: c.....)
end
```

The third-party app doesn't accept arguments that are `nil`. That is, each parameter must either have a value or must not be passed.

Is there a way to check if the optional parameters passed to `func1` have a value, and **only pass those parameters** further to `call_to_client_internal` that do? In this case the optional ones are  `a` and `e`.

Comment: Nice question here @Akato - enjoyed digging into it to find a solution! Definite +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're Ruby 2.1 + there's a way to do it:

```
def foo(a: nil, b:nil, c: nil, d: nil, e: nil)
  present_args = method(__method__).parameters.select { |arg| binding.local_variable_get(arg[1]) }
  ...
end
```

This:

- gets the available args with `method(:foo).parameters`
- gets their values with `binding.local_variable_get(arg[1])`
- selects these to use as needed, stored in `present_args` (I'm sure you can think of a better name

So, for your case, I'd expand this to use `reduce`:

```
def func1(a: nil, b:nil, c: nil, d: nil, e: nil)
  present_args_hash = method(__method__).parameters.reduce({}) do |hash, (_, arg)| 
    next hash unless (val = binding.local_variable_get(arg))
    hash.merge(arg => val)
  end
  call_to_client_internal(present_args_hash)
end
```

This looks a nice straightforward way of doing this - you build a hash of only those keyword args that are present, and send it off to your client.

Let me know how you get on! Any questions, happy to help out.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps you could use `__method__` instead of hard coding `:foo` or `:func1` in your examples.

Comment: too much of metaprogramming for such a simple thing, I believe

Comment: Thanks for the `__method__` steer Sahar. And I'd tend to agree @nattfodd; I'm really surprised there's not a better built in solution. I wanted to offer a direct solution to the scenario described (partly because I was enjoying digging into it), but would say restructuring the args would be sensible.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a simpler way upon suggested:

```
# ** means func1 accepts only named parameters
# options is a hash of optional parameters
# .compact removes all nil values from hash
def func1(b:, c:, d:, **options)
  # if you want, you can leave only those option params you want:
  options = options.slice(:a, :e)

  # For Ruby 2.4 and above
  options = options.merge(b: b, c: c, d: d).compact
  # For Ruby 2.3 and below
  options = options.merge(b: b, c: c, d: d).reject { |_, v| v.nil? }
  call_to_client_internal(options)
end
```

Comment: I agree with this solution as it is the most apparent. Please note that `Hash#compact` requires ruby 2.4 or greater

Comment: Why isn't it `def func1(b:,c:,d:,**options)`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to delete the keys before even passing it to `func1`
something like

```
hash = {a: nil, b: b, c: c, d: d, e: nil}.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
func1(hash)
```

Also your function should look like:

```
def func1(a: nil, b: nil, c: nil, d: nil, e: nil)
  #
end
```

Another approach would to simply pass `hash` variable everywhere.this way you can pass the same hash variable further to `call_to_client..` method.

```
hash = {a: nil, b: b, c: c, d: d, e: nil}.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
func1(hash)

def func1(hash)
 # use hash[:a] and so on
 call_to_client_internal(hash)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just create a new `hash` as it seems a safe solution to me. You can do something like this ( *assuming a is the initial hash* )

```
b = {}
a.each{|k,v| b[k] = v if !v.nil?}
```

And then pass `b` to your function as the input hash.